# Reorder levels of facet_wrap using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an existing dataset with three factors. I would like to plot these three factors using facet_grid() and have them ordered based on how they are ordered in the dataset instead of alphabetical order. Is this possible to do somehow without modifying my data structure?

Here's the data:

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22681355/data.csv

data<-read.csv("data.csv", head=T)

ggplot(data, aes(time,a, color="one")) + 
    geom_line(linetype=1, size=0.3) + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,1,0.2)) + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(100,300,50)) + 
    theme_bw() + 
    geom_line(aes(time,b)) + 
    geom_line(aes(time,c)) + 
    geom_line(aes(time,d))+facet_wrap(~X.1)
```

Comment: how do you get `net` from `data`?

Comment: sorry that was a mistake

Comment: have you tried running this command yourself? There's only 1 observation for each facet. Are you aware of this?

Comment: another mistake due to dataset export please see the edit facet should not be X but X.1

Comment: See [this blog post](http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2012/10/15/how-do-i-re-arrange-ordering-a-plot/) about the words `reorder` and `plot` when used in the same sentence.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This question appears quite too often on SO. You've to get the desired column (by which you're facetting) as a factor with levels in the order you desire, as follows:

```
data$X.1 <- factor(data$X.1, levels=unique(data$X.1))
```

Now, plot it and you'll get the facetted plot in the desired order.

[image]

Comment: You'll only get the facets in the correct order if the factor order is correct. Don't forget you can set the order separate to the levels.